# Geode spring boot Cache Client Updater Thread crash

Tags: spring-boot-data-geode

Using

```
implementation 'org.springframework.geode:spring-geode-starter:1.2.8.RELEASE'    
implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-geode:2.2.8.RELEASE'
```

I setup a listener

```
@Service
public class LQuote extends CacheListenerAdapter {
...afterCreate...
...afterUpdate...
}
```

When an event comes to the local cache from the server the `Cache Client Updater Thread` reads the event using `readPdxSerializable pdxType` but when it is trying to load the domain object class it hits an `endpoint Crashed` issue:

```
TRACE [Cache Client Updater Thread  on 1.2.3.4(ServerUAT:6392)<v1>:41001(version:UNKNOWN[ordinal=105]) port 40404] org.apache.geode.internal.ClassPathLoader 156 forName: forName trying: java.net.URLClassLoader@3b8b4846
DEBUG [Cache Client Updater Thread  on 1.2.3.4(ServerUAT:6392)<v1>:41001(version:UNKNOWN[ordinal=105]) port 40404] org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.InstantiatorRecoveryListener 63 endpointCrashed: InstantiatorRecoveryTask - EndpointCrashed. Now have 0 endpoints
DEBUG [Cache Client Updater Thread  on 1.2.3.4(ServerUAT:6392)<v1>:41001(version:UNKNOWN[ordinal=105]) port 40404] org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.DataSerializerRecoveryListener 51 endpointCrashed: DataSerializerRecoveryTask - EndpointCrashed. Now have 0 endpoints
INFO  [Cache Client Updater Thread  on 1.2.3.4(ServerUAT:6392)<v1>:41001(version:UNKNOWN[ordinal=105]) port 40404] org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.QueueManagerImpl 372 endpointCrashed: Primary subscription endpoint 1.2.3.4:40404 crashed. Scheduling recovery.
```

I guess this could be because the domain object class does not override `ToData` and `FromData` or `FromPdx` and `ToPdx` according to [Implementing PdxSerializable](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/19/developing/data_serialization/use_pdx_serializable.html) but adding these, or adding

```
@Region
public class Quote implements DataSerializable {
```

with `toData` and `fromData` has no effect. The issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

The way to resolve this was, like, to specify domain objects for all the objects that I want to use.

```
class myObject1 implements PdxSerializable {

...

public void toData(PdxWriter writer)
{
    writer.writeString("MsgType", MsgType);
    ...
}

public void fromData(PdxReader reader)
{
    MsgType = reader.readString("MsgType");
    ....
}
```